# What does “&” mean in “linkerd viz dashboard &”?

Tags: linkerd

I am reading Linkerd Getting Started docs. I saw a command at [Step 4: Explore Linkerd](https://linkerd.io/2.10/getting-started/#step-4-explore-linkerd) that start Linkerd viz dashboard.

Is there any difference between

```
linkerd viz dashboard &
```

and

```
linkerd viz dashboard
```

Both commands work and start the dashboard.

What does `&` mean?

Comment: Is this a Linux command line? Then it starts in the background, you get the prompt back before the command ends

Comment: Yeah the answer helps, thanks both SiKing and Hans!